# Can i run Azure Functions in code?

Tags: c#, azure, timer, azure-functions

Can i run Azure Functions in code?

I mean, that having some c# project and host it on Azure i want to user `Timer` to do background work time by time.
Have Azure SDK (or so on) some methods to implements timer line `Azure Functions` but in code?

P.S. i mean than can i use somelike Azure Function methods in App Service?
For example, i want to run some piece of code every 5 minute, but not all code.

Hm.. thank you for your answers!
What i mean:

```
 var azureTimer=new AzureFunctionTimer(5*60*1000);
 azureTimer.Elapsed+=SomeHandler;
```

Where `AzureFunctionTimer` is a part of Azure SDK (for example).

Why am i ask? I think (and may be i am wrong) that using a some timer like `System.Threading.Timer` utilize CPU timer at Azure host even event of elapsed time not rising yet.

For example:

```
  var timer=new Timer(5*60*1000);
      timer.Elapsed+=SomeHandler; 
      timer.Start(); //and while timer not rise event it utilize CPU already. (Am i right?)
```

And to prevent it should use some Azure SDK function like `Azure Function` (if it exist).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question - can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but if you're trying to use Azure Functions to run something every 5 minutes (or whatever period), you can make a timer function. This means that the function will automatically trigger every 5 minutes and run your code. When you use the Azure Dashboard to create a new function, one of the templates is for "Timer" which will let you run some code every period you define.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant use Timers, Azure Functions will shutdown after 5 minutes, but you can call them externally on a timer (webhooks), or use internal Azure Functions cron schedule or other events, like new message in a queue.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions works in a reactive way, it will only run when an event happen. 
So the best you can do is use a kind of trigger (http Trigger for example) and call your Azure Function when you need.

Comment: i write new text about it